# Setting up test coverage and thresholds with create react app and typescript

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, create-react-app

Following the example here https://create-react-app.dev/docs/running-tests/

my package.json now has...

Package.json

```
  "jest": {
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
      "!<rootDir>/node_modules/"
    ],
    "coverageThreshold": {
      "global": {
        "branches": 90,
        "functions": 90,
        "lines": 90,
        "statements": 90
      }
    },
    "coverageReporters": [
      "text"
    ],
    "snapshotSerializers": [
      "my-serializer-module"
    ]
  },
```

I run `CI=true npm test`

And I get the error

```
● Validation Error:

  Module my-serializer-module in the snapshotSerializers option was not found.
         <rootDir> is: /Users/me/Documents/Proj/React/my-app

  Configuration Documentation:
  https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration.html
```

Answer (score 0):

### Maybe you should try to watch what is a testing library and how setup yours!

---

You don't have to compile your TS for run test on it but you should try to get a look at [jest.io](https://jest.io) and [testing-library.com](https://testing-library.com) is not complicated to setup testing library at all.